# Pass parameter to Facebook login callback

Tags: php, facebook, session, callback, facebook-oauth

I've this simply facebook login integration.
I need to pass to the callback (that in this case is this same page) a custom parameter but the new $helper->getLoginUrl does not allow adding params. Previuosly I see that there was a next parameter that can be used to store a string but now it was removed. 
It seems that I can't add a custom param neither in the session. 
Is there any method to achieve my purpose?

```
<?php 
require '../facebooksrc/autoload.php';

$userdata='/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,gender,location,birthday';
$permissions = ['email, user_location, publish_actions, user_birthday'];

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $appid,
  'app_secret' => $appsecret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
  ]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state'];

try {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    } else {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
 }
if (isset($accessToken)) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    } else {
        // getting short-lived access token
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
        // OAuth 2.0 client handler
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one

        //$longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        //$_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
        // setting default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }
    // redirect the user back to the same page if it has "code" GET variable
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        header('Location: ./');
    }
    // getting basic info about user
    try {
        $profile_request = $fb->get($userdata);
        $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();

    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }


    $firstname=$profile["first_name"];
    $lastname=$profile["last_name"];

    // MY INSERT QUERY  

} else {
    $url="myurl";

    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($url, $permissions);

    //REDIRECT
    header("Location: $loginUrl");

}
```

Comment: _"but the new $helper->getLoginUrl does not allow adding params"_ - it allows you to specify the URL to redirect to, so where is the problem with appending your parameters to the query string of that ...?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I thought that the getLoginUrl will not consider the "?param=test" for security reason, as Google do.